# C# Not all data passes from one Form to another

Tags: c#

I have problems passing all data I need from one form to another. Below you can see the data I want to pass, but what happens is, it passes only (_12nc, BID, device, orderNr) but not List<>steps.

```
Steps stepsForm = new Steps(ref steps, _12nc, BID, device, orderNr);
```

But if I try to pass only List<>steps, than steps is passed:

```
Steps stepsForm = new Steps(ref steps)
```

How can I pass both List and individual values?

This is code from where I want to pass data:

```
private void btn_start_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Step> steps = new List<Step>();
        int device;
        string _12nc;
        int BID;
        int orderNr;

        device = Convert.ToInt32(txt_device.Text);
        _12nc = txt_12nc.Text;
        BID = Convert.ToInt32(txt_BID.Text);
        orderNr = Convert.ToInt32(txt_OrderNr.Text);

        // Get list of steps (ID and Description)
        steps = myDBHelper.GetSteps(_12nc,device, BID);          

        // Open new form and pass steps to it
        Steps stepsForm = new Steps(ref steps, _12nc, BID, device, orderNr); //, _12nc, BID, device, orderNr
        stepsForm.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
```

And this is where I want to pass it to:

```
    public partial class Steps : Form
{
    private List<Step> steps = new List<Step>();
    private List<Parameter> param = new List<Parameter>();

    private String _12nc;
    private int BID;
    private int device;
    private int orderNr;


    public Steps(ref List<Step> steps, string _12nc, int BID, int device, int orderNr)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.steps = steps;
        this._12nc = _12nc;
        this.BID = BID;
        this.device = device;
        this.orderNr = orderNr;
        RefreshLabels();
    }
```

Comment: if you pass it, its passed period. `but not List<>steps` is just your assumption

Comment: Yes, I can see that steps are filled

Comment: you dont have to pass List with ref, I guess your problem is solved?

Comment: Nope, it does not change anything ;/

Comment: Agree with Sushil, Don't need to pass ref, simply pass it as a parameter and you will get the value of steps. Hopefully this will work

Comment: I still get the same result. Can see only:     string _12nc, int BID, int device, int orderNr passed

Comment: I have added answer code, Please modify it as per your requirement, It is working fine at my machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify below code as per your requirement, I have check it is working fine.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        List<Step> steps = new List<Step>();
        Step objStep = new Step();
        int device;

        device = 32;
        objStep._12nc = "dsfdsF";
        objStep.BID = 3;
        objStep.orderNr = 12;

        // Get list of steps (ID and Description)
        //steps = myDBHelper.GetSteps(_12nc, device, BID);
        steps.Add(objStep);
        // Open new form and pass steps to it
        Form2 stepsForm = new Form2(steps, objStep, device); //, _12nc, BID, device, orderNr
        stepsForm.Show();
        this.Hide();
    }
}
```

Second form

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
     private List<Step> steps = new List<Step>();
private List<Parameter> param = new List<Parameter>();

private String _12nc;
private int BID;
private int device;
private int orderNr;


public Form2(List<Step> steps, Step objStep, int device)
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.steps = steps;
    this._12nc = objStep._12nc;
    this.BID = objStep.BID;
    this.device = device;
    this.orderNr = objStep.orderNr;
    //RefreshLabels();
}
}
public class Step
{
    public string _12nc { get; set; }
    public int BID { get; set; }
    public int orderNr { get; set; }
}
public class Parameter
{
}
```